# Update MySQL within Perl loop failing (fetchrow_array)

Tags: mysql, perl

I've created a Perl script which is meant to loop through an array (a shortlist of customers who meet certain criteria), execute an external command using system() , then update a field within each row once the operation has completed.

It works on the first record (ie external command executes, customer record updates), however when it gets to the second record I receive this error:

DBD::mysql::st fetchrow_array failed: fetch() without execute() at customer_update.pl

Through some googling I added the $sth->finish(); command, however whether I include it or not (either inside the loop as shown, or straight afterward) I still get the same error.

Can anyone shed any light for me as to what I am doing wrong here?

Here's an extract:

```
# PERL MYSQL CONNECT()
$dbh = DBI->connect('dbi:mysql:signups', $user, $pw) 
or die "Connection Error: $DBI::errstr\n";

# DEFINE A MySQL QUERY
$myquery = "SELECT * FROM accounts WHERE field3 = false";
$sth = $dbh->prepare($myquery);

# EXECUTE THE QUERY
$sth->execute
or die "SQL Error: $DBI::errstr\n";

@records = $sth->rows;
print "Amount of new customers: @records\n\n";

while ( my ($field1, $field2, $field3) = $sth->fetchrow_array() ) {
    #execute external command via system();
    $update_customer_status = "UPDATE accounts SET field3=true WHERE id=$id";
    $sth = $dbh->prepare($update_customer_status);
    $sth->execute
    or die "SQL Error: $DBI::errstr\n";
    print "Customer record modified & MySQL updated accordingly\n\n";   
    $sth->finish();
}
```

Comment: What is the external command that you are going to call?  Normally one wouldn't execute a `select` and then update each of the results via a separate `update` command, when you could easily move the `where` clause used in the select statement to the where clause of the update statement.

Comment: `finish` is used when you don't want to iterate over the rest of the results returned by `SELECT`. It's useless after an `UPDATE`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Building a SQL statement with variables and then prepare()ing it defeats the purpose of the prepare.  You should build the SQL statement with a placeholder `?` instead of `$id`, prepare() it, and then execute($id) it.  As it is, you are leaving yourself open to SQL injection attacks.

Also, it seems that you are not using the `warnings` and `strict` pragmas.  These two lines should be at the top of every program you write:

```
use warnings;
use strict;
```

They will save you much heartache and frustration in the future.

Answer (score 4):

In your loop, you overwrite the handle over from which you are fetching. Use a different variable. (Changing `$sth = ...;` to `my $sth = ...;` will do.) While we're at it, let's move the `prepare` out of the loop.

```
my $sth_get = $dbh->prepare("SELECT * FROM accounts WHERE field3 = false");
my $sth_upd = $dbh->prepare("UPDATE accounts SET field3=true WHERE id = ?");

$sth_get->execute();
while ( my ($field1, $field2, $field3) = $sth_get->fetchrow_array() ) {
    ...
    $sth_upd->execute($id);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You are stomping on your `$sth` variable when you execute this line ...

```
$sth = $dbh->prepare($update_customer_status);
```

Why not save off the result of `$sth->fetchrow_array()` to an array variable.
Something like ...

```
my @select_results_AoA = $sth->fetchrow_array();
```

... and then iterate over the array ...

```
for my @row ( @select_resilts_AoA ) {
```

... instead of ...

```
while ( my ($field1, $field2, $field3) = $sth->fetchrow_array() ) {
```

Comment: Right problem, but your solution doesn't help at all. Maybe you meant to use `selectall_arrayref`?

Comment: @ikegami Yes `selectall_arrayref` would be more appropriate. Thanks.